# folder within jenkins workspace is turned into a file and i don't understand why

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

My Jenkins job builds my project and runs some protractor tests - the results of these tests are copied inside the "TestResults" folder of my Jenkins work space.

my problem is: after 1-2 months of this job running everyday with no issues - the folder gets turned into a file - can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

this is how my jenkins pipeline looks:

```
node('IW.NEXT-UI Protractor Tests') {

    stage('Run protractor test scripts') {
        try{
            //run bat scripts at below location - they include protractor tests
            bat 'C:\\Sources\\iw-next\\iw.next-ui\\e2e\\protractor-tests\\scripts\\_startTests.bat'

        }
        //equivallent to post build step
        finally{
            //bat 'C:\\Users\\testpmo\\Desktop\\test.bat'
            junit '**/TestResults/*.xml'
        }

    }
}
```

these are the scripts that are ran inside the job:

1.

```
cd C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts

rem timeout /T 5 & 0ini
rem *** ping locally 5 times before running 0init.bat - simulates timeout command ***
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 & 0init.bat
```

2.

```
    DATE /T & TIME /T & C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\2gitActions_1.bat 
& C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\2gitActions_2.bat 
& C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\3buildProject.bat 
& C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\4protractorTests.bat 
& C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\5transfer.bat 
& C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\scripts\6deleteOutput.bat 
& exit
```

3.

```
cd C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui
git reset --hard

rem *** added user and pass otherwise pull would not work using jenkins slave node ***
git pull [repo here]
del package-lock.json
npm install
```

4.

```
cd C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui & ng build --target=development --environment=dev
```

5.

```
cd C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests
protractor conf.js --suite full
```

6.

```
echo f| xcopy /e /v "C:\Sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\output" "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test - IW.NEXT-UI\TestResults"
```

7.

```
cd C:\sources\iw-next\iw.next-ui\e2e\protractor-tests\output
del /F /Q *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your folder got corrupted. If this is the case you may find this link useful. https://superuser.com/questions/42202/how-to-recover-folder-converted-to-file-by-check-disk

Was there any warning for program or system crash before the issue occured? 
How big was the folder? 
We delete our workspaces and test results regularly. Here is the plugin that we use. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin

Comment: the folder probably less than 10 mb (90 test results text files of about 60 kb each).
did not see any warning or system crash before it happened - we don`t really log on that machine unless we need to - We did however restart the machine about 2 times - but i don`t think that was the cause as the jenkins job ran without any issues after the machine was back up.

Our workspace is regularly cleaned - the only folder that remains there is the tests folder.